# Case Else in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I'm converting VBScript to PowerShell and I have an issue with `Select Case`. I'm trying to find a way to do a `Case Else`.

```
switch($IncomingText.SubString(0,1)) {
    "1" {
        switch($IncomingText.SubString(12,3)) {
            "601" {
                $TempString = ($IncomingText.SubString(0,75))

                if (RemoveSpaces($IncomingText.SubString(75,10)) = True) {
                    $TempString = $TempString + (StrReverse($IncomingText.SubString(75,10))) + ($IncomingText.SubString(85,10))
                } else {
                    $TempString = $TempString + ($IncomingText.SubString(75,20))
                }
                return $TempString

                Case Else
                if (RemoveSpaces($IncomingText.SubString(155,10)) = True) {
                    $TempString = $TempString + (StrReverse($IncomingText.SubString(155,10))) + ($IncomingText.SubString(165))
                } else {
                    $TempString = $TempString + ($IncomingText.SubString(155))
                }
                return $TempString
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In VBScript there's this `Case Else`. I want to stay in the **"601"** and proceed with the next section. How do I do it in PowerShell? Since `Case Else` doesn't seems to be working for me.

Comment: Don't do a 1-for-1 translation of your VBScript to PowerShell just by altering the syntax. Rewrite it entirely in conventional PowerShell.

Comment: Did you do any research on this? Like, at all? Because that should immediately have brought up the [VBScript-to-Windows PowerShell Conversion Guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848796.aspx) featuring [this little gem](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176957.aspx) (among other things).

Answer (score 4):

Taken from Windows Powershell site
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730937.aspx

So use default instead of case else.

```
$a = 5
switch ($a) 
{ 
    1 {"The color is red."} 
    2 {"The color is blue."} 
    3 {"The color is green."} 
    4 {"The color is yellow."} 
    5 {"The color is orange."} 
    6 {"The color is purple."} 
    7 {"The color is pink."}
    8 {"The color is brown."} 
    default {"The color could not be determined."}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for `default`:

```
Switch ($something) {
   1 { .. }
   2 { .. }
   default { .. }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to point out that the `Switch` command will evaluate scriptblocks similar to an `If` statement, so you could just create more complex cases:

```
switch($IncomingText) {
    {$_.SubString(0,1) -eq '1' -and $IncomingText.SubString(12,3) -eq '601'} 
                {
                    $TempString = $IncomingText.SubString(0,75)

                    if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($IncomingText.SubString(75,10))) {
                        $TempString = $TempString + (StrReverse($IncomingText.SubString(75,10))) + ($IncomingText.SubString(85,10))
                    } else {
                        $TempString = $TempString + ($IncomingText.SubString(75,20))
                    }
                }

     default    
                {
                    if (RemoveSpaces($IncomingText.SubString(155,10)) = True) {
                        $TempString = $TempString + (StrReverse($IncomingText.SubString(155,10))) + ($IncomingText.SubString(165))
                    } else {
                        $TempString = $TempString + ($IncomingText.SubString(155))
                    }
                    return $TempString
                }
}
```

I would also like to note that it looks like you are removing spaces from a 10 character string, and testing to see if anything is left. If there is you reverse those 10 characters, then add the next 10 characters, if not you simply add all 20 characters as they are. My point is that if the first 10 characters are all spaces then reversing them is harmless, so you may as well just always reverse them. With that in mind your code gets a lot simpler:

```
Function StrReverse ($MyString){
    $arrMyString = $MyString.ToCharArray()
    [array]::Reverse($arrMyString)
    $arrMyString -join ''
}

switch($IncomingText) {
    {$_.SubString(0,1) -eq '1' -and $IncomingText.SubString(12,3) -eq '601'} 
                {
                    $TempString = $IncomingText.SubString(0,75) + (StrReverse $IncomingText.SubString(75,10)) + $IncomingText.SubString(85,10)
                }

     default    
                {
                    $TempString + (StrReverse $IncomingText.SubString(155,10)) + $IncomingText.SubString(165)
                }
}
```